# C++ wait for all async operation end

Tags: c++, asynchronous, boost, boost-asio

I have started `N` same async operations(e.g. `N` requests to database), so i need to do something after all this operations end. How i can do this? (After one async operation end, my callback will be called). 
I use C++14

 **Example**
i use `boost.asio` to write some data to socket.

```
for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i)
{
boost::asio::async_write(
        m_socket, 
        boost::asio::buffer(ptr[i], len[i]), 
            [this, callback](const boost::system::error_code& ec, std::size_t )
            {
                callback(ec);
            });
}
```

So i need to know when all my writes ends;

Comment: What do you mean by "after one async operation end, my callback will be called"? Are you using [`std::async`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/async)? Can you please try to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and show us?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg add some example

Answer (score 2):

first of all, never call async_write in a loop. Each socket may have only one async_write and one async_read outstanding at any one time.

boost already has provision for scatter/gather io.

This snippet should give you enough information to go on.

Notice that async_write can take a vector of vectors as a 'buffer' and it will fire the handler exactly once, once all the buffers have been written.

```
struct myclass {

    boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket m_socket;

    std::vector<std::vector<char>> pending_buffers;
    std::vector<std::vector<char>> writing_buffers;

    void write_all()
    {
        assert(writing_buffers.size() == 0);
        writing_buffers = std::move(pending_buffers);

        boost::asio::async_write(
                                 m_socket,
                                 boost::asio::buffer(writing_buffers),
                                 std::bind(&myclass::write_all_handler,
                                           this,
                                           std::placeholders::_1,
                                           std::placeholders::_2));
    }

    void write_all_handler(const boost::system::error_code& ec, size_t bytes_written)
    {
        writing_buffers.clear();
        // send next load of data
        if (pending_buffers.size())
            write_all();

        // call your callback here
    }
};
```

Comment: Very nice and succinct. I have not seen scatter/gather presented so brief before.

Comment: aww shucks :) In seriousness, the documentation for asio is awful, which is a crime since the library is probably the finest and most useful piece of programming i have ever seen. It really should be part of the c++ standard.

Comment: Aside from the rough index, I have found the documentation to be remarkable good.  However, I often find it easier to search through the PDF documentation, rather than the individual HTML pages.  Also, the Library Evolution Working Group (LEWG) voted to base the Networking 
TS on Boost.Asio (see [here](http://lists.boost.org/Archives/boost/2014/06/214809.php)), and the [asio repository](https://github.com/chriskohlhoff/asio) has some changes based on LEWG feedback.